# Is it acceptable to recommend a book in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

Today I found a question for which I think a book I've read might bring the information the OP is looking for. I've commented the question with the book recommendation, but now I wonder if it's a good practice on SO.

I know it's common to give a link to an external resource in a comment, but I feel a book is different because it's a merchandise, so my comment could be seen as a form of advertising.

Do you think recommending a book in the comment is a good practice, as long as it does match the following criterions ?

- The OP is not asking for a book recommendation (off-topic)
- The author of the comment is not affiliated with the book author/editor, i.e. has nothing to win or lose with this recommendation, or mentions his/her affiliation
- There's a brief explanation on what in this book may be useful
- The recommendation is in a comment, or is a complement to an answer (no book-only answer)

Comment: The OP did ask for a recommendation, a book that describes the subject in fine detail is an excellent recommendation.  You can't post it as an answer so a comment is all you got.  It is however unlikely to survive for long so that's five minutes of your life you'll never get back.  You'd have to edit the question to turn it into something that isn't spam-bait, along with an answer that is more than just a "read this book". recommendation.

Comment: @HansPassant You're right, the OP did ask for it. It's too bad because he seems totally open to an answer fully on SO, anyway his question was also a bit too broad. I'll edit my question to stop referring to this one, so it doesn't contradict the answer to my question.

Comment: I think I've recommended C# noobs to read CLR Via C# about a billion times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly what you can use comments for. They can be either be used for asking the OP to precise the question or to explain something further or to give to the OP the direction in which he can find the answer. Tutorial, documentation, book url or anything that is helpful but doesn't match community standards and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).